# AWS Bitnami enable https on Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, bitnami

I currently have a MEAN stack app powered by Bitnami running on an Ec2 instance. The site works fine except for https.

What I've done so far:

checked instance to ensure port 443 is enabled
created certificate using openssl. I now have 3 files *.crt, *.key, *.csr.
I put my certificate files in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/ directory.
edited 3 lines in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf to point to the correct files.
restarted server using the command: /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart

Now when I go to https://my-site-name I just get an error saying the connection was unexpectedly closed.

This is my first time deploying to AWS and I'm not really sure where to go from here. I don't know what steps I missed or even how to go about finding the root of the problem.

Comment: Where did you enabled that port 443 in security group right?

Comment: Thats correct. I went to the security group and HTTPS is enabled in the inbound settings.

Comment: What about port 80 is it open too?

Comment: Port 80 is open as well

Comment: Ok what happens when you connect to site like this http ://my-site-name

Comment: The site works as expected but does not let me use the security features.

Comment: Run this command on the server sudo yum install mod_ssl -y

Comment: results in an error: sudo: yum: command not found

Comment: Ok use this command sudo a2enmod ssl and restart Apache

Comment: Same error: a2enmod: command not found

Comment: Use this 1. sudo chown root:root /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*

Comment: After above command run this 2. sudo chmod 600 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*

Comment: And after above command 3. sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Comment: Did all 3 commands with no success. They all ran fine but still no https

Comment: I guess what happened is you followed the incorrect guide (Bitnami Cloud) for setting up the SSL check this link https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_enable_HTTPS_support_with_SSL_certificates you have to follow the Virtual machine guide http://imgur.com/a/GEhPj

Comment: error2007, you were correct.  I followed the guide you linked to and everything works. If you want to post that as an answer I will mark it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ok I did it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your use case is your were following incorrect guide please use this guide which is for AWS EC2 instance and will work correctly.

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_enable_HTTPS_support_with_SSL_certificates

Comment: This is showing nothing but a list of documentations Bitnami uses.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fully working SSL on AWS Bitnami Wordpress use the following documentation https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/ it always worked and the whole setup took only 5 minutes at max.